# Font Awesome Unicode in select option breaks on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, unicode, font-awesome

I have a select with currencies like this:

```
<select class="new-challenge-bet-currency">
    <option value="usd">&#xf155;</option>
    <option value="eur">&#xf153;</option>
    <!-- keeps going with more currencies -->
</select>
```

Everything works fine on desktop browsers, and the mobile browser even displays the `fa` currency symbol on the `selected` item.

Here is a screenshot of what happens on Chrome Android. As you can see, the selected currency ($) at the top display fine, but the white box that pops up when it's time to select a different option just displays broken X boxes.

[image]

Any idea how to get them to work? Looking for a simple solution so I don't have to rework how currency selection is done all together.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just mobile, there has historically been difficulty in styling `<option>` as it has been rendered by native OS widgets instead of browser DOM. If you really must completely control the presentation of a `<select>` box you will need to replace it with scripted element. (See [select2](https://select2.github.io/) et al.)

However it is unclear to me why you are using Private Use Area characters with custom glyphs to render currency symbols for which there are perfectly good Unicode characters (U+0024 Dollar Sign, U+20AC Euro Sign) available. If you can use real Unicode characters (still with custom font rendering if you prefer), then they should still be usable when displayed by non-browser widgets like this.

Comment: The main reason I'm using FA is because there is no raw Unicode way of printing the Bitcoin symbol. Maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: Probably the best you could do with pure Unicode would be with combining lines, B̩̍. With a custom font you could could try putting the glyphs you want on $, € and B, so at least they fall back to usable symbols without the font in cases like this.